# Soft deleting huge user accounts with a background task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, delayed-job

I'm using Rails and devise for an app that stores a lot of data on users. I want to make it possible for a user to deactivate his account similar to the way Facebook does it so that if you log back in, your account gets reactivated. So far I've tackled this using a soft delete. Problem is, when people delete their accounts, there's so much data that needs to be soft deleted that it takes a while to run. Naturally, my instinct was to use delayed_job for this. But the problem is, this only works on account deletion, not on reactivation. I don't want my users to have to sit around for 10 second while all their data is restored, but I also can't do it in the background, because then they'll be logged back in before any of their data has been restored.

Any ideas as to how to go about solving this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For temporal deactivation a simple flag would be the better option in my opinion. The deletion-to-be-performed could be recorded in a seperate table.

Comment: Problem there is that when an account is deactivated, I don't want any of its associations to be visible either, so everything needs to be flagged, not just the user.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to set your soft_delete to be tracked as a boolean flag on all the relevant records. Set your default scopes to return only records that don't have the flag set. When it comes time to activate or deactivate, gather all your relevant records and hit them with `update_all`. Here's an example run against 13,000 user records to give you a sense of time & performance:

```
1.9.2p320 :001 > User.update_all(soft_deleted: false)
  SQL (1016.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "soft_deleted" = 'f'
 => 13350
```

As you see, it hit all 13,000 records with that flag toggle in about one second. So, if you wanted to hit a User, all of a user's Posts, and all of a users PrivateMessages,

```
User.update_attributes(soft_deleted: true)
User.posts.update_all(soft_deleted: true)
User.private_messages.update_all(soft_deleted: true)
```

And you should be good to go. If you're dealing with so many records that even this technique doesn't perform well, I don't think you're going to have much choice except to tell the user it may be a few moments before all their data is available on reactivation and throw the whole process into a background job, as you originally planned.

Comment: Makes sense. The reason it's taking so long for me is that I'm using acts_as_paranoid to handle my soft deletes, and when I run a delete, I get thousand of these: (0.4ms)  UPDATE "follows" SET "deleted_at" = NULL, "updated_at" = '2013-04-09 21:49:46.886209' WHERE "follows"."id" = 2348. It does each one individually, and it takes forever. I think the reasoning has something to do with validation, but whatever it is, it's causing trouble. Any thoughts on a workaround?

Comment: I'm surprised that acts_as_paranoid is doing things that way, but it's rather an older library. I don't know if rails3_acts_as_paranoid is any better, but at this juncture I'd either look into that or refactor acts_as_paranoid out of the repo entirely and roll my own soft-delete options.

Comment: It's looking like that might be the way to go. I'm already using rails3_acts_as_paranoid, so I suppose there's not much else I can do.

Comment: If you go the roll-your-own path, it's probably worth pointing out that `update_all` skips validations, so that instruction should stay very high-performance.

Comment: Duly noted. I'll keep you posted on how it goes.